# UTF8 with PHP and MySQL error

Tags: php, mysql

I got a form that allow user to submit data. I set the collation of the whole table in the database as `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

However when I tried to input non-English characters, what I get in the field is something like `&auml;&frac12;&nbsp;&ccedil;‡!!&aring;&curren`.....
When I later echo the data out with php, similar illegible characters appers.

Is it the problem with my form submission? Or is PHP capable of output the correct data from the strang strings in mysql?

Comment: [How to handle Unicode in a web app](http://kunststube.net/frontback)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are inserting html encoded strings into your sql server. Somewhere you are missing to html_entity_decode()

Answer (score 0):

For database(in the php file), if you are pulling data from query

```
$db->set_charset('utf8');  or mysql_set_charset('utf8',$db);
```

Also I would suggest using utf8 general-ci for all languages.